# fork() in C and memory representation of shared memory in POSIX

Tags: c, memory, posix, fork, shared-memory

I am working on `POSIX` shared memory.

I do not understand the internal implementation. How the processes share the memory.
I saw some videos telling that the process actually do not share the memory, i.e. if process-A and process-B shares some variable say x, then the logical page that contains x, within both the processes A and B actually pointing to the same frame in the main memory, this is how processes share the memory.

My questions are:

1. This is what (as I mention above) happens when we `fork()` the process? (I mean suppose process-A has opened file1 file2 and had variable a,b,c now if process-A forked process-B , can process-B access all those files and variables.)
2. If no, then how to achieve that implementation?
3. If yes, then how to have shared memory between unrelated processes?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, the two processes have their own independent copies of everything.  Note that these copies might be incompatible; having both processes write to a common file might end in tears, for example.
2. You can't; you need to explicitly share everything you want to share.
3. Use `shm_open` and friends.

Comment: For (2) the forked processes share open file descriptions; if one moves the current position pointer, it also moves in the other.  The variables are not shared, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Process has 4 segments

1. code segment
2. data segment
3. stack segment
4. heap segment

when `fork()` is executed, child process will have it's own data,heap and stack segments created which are the exact replica of parent's. But code segment will be shared between parent and child.

That is why you will be able to see same values of variables if not changed.

Each process has it's own local file descriptor table. each entry in a local FDT holds a reference to a global FileTable. Entry in a FT holds information about opened files(like offset and all). When data segment is duplicated to child process, child and parent points to same entry in FileTable. And because of that you can say that child and parent share the file descriptor.

Please note that when two process open same file together, they don't share entry in global FileTable. Two different Entries are made at that time.

I assume above information answers your first question.

For sharing variables explicitly between processes, `shm` library would be helpful reading.

Answer (score -1):

The child process inherits all IPC features from the parent - that is, both processes will be still attached to the same segment after the `fork()`.

In general (cases 2, 3) you *attach* to a shared memory segment from an arbitrary process by using a "key" which is supposed to identify that segment at creation.